# Swift Passing Data Structs and Arrays Firebase

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, pass-data

I am trying to send data from vc_1 to vc_2. But I am observing the submitted data is missing in vc_2 (Basket items). How can ı observe all data in vc_2?

Firebase node;

```
Pro_:
     Basket:
        ID_1:
           cat: “Tech”
           info:”iOS” 
           orderid:”Ref_1” 
        ID_2:
           cat: “Tech”
           info:”Android” 
           orderid:”Ref_2” 
     name:”Mike”
```

First_VC

```
    var name_list = [Name_Struct]()
    var SecondArray : [BasketArray] = []

    func retrieve_data(){
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        self.ref.child(“Pro_”).observeSingleEvent(of:.value) { (snapshot) in
            self.name_list.removeAll()
            for child in snapshot.children{
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let dict = snap.value as! NSDictionary
                        let name_ = dict[“name”] as? String ?? ""
                let baskets = (child as AnyObject).childSnapshot(forPath: “Basket”).value as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
                for basket in baskets {
                    let pro_detail = basket.value as? [String: Any]
                    let info_ = basket?[“info”] as? String ?? ""
                    let cat_ = basket?[“cat”] as? String ?? ""
                    let orderid_ = basket?[“orderid”] as? String ?? ""
                    self.SecondArray.append(BasketArray(info: info_, cat: cat_, orderid: orderid_)
                }
                    let names = Name_Struct(name: name_)
                            self.name_list.append(names)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }}}}}
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         if let destination = segue.destination as? Second_VC {
            destination.SecondArray = SecondArray[indexPath.row]
            print(“Send array:”,self.SecondArray)
        }}
```

Send array output

> Send array: [“cat”: “Tech”, “info”: “iOS”, “orderid”: “Ref_1”]
> Send array: [“cat”: “Tech”, “info”: “Android”, “orderid”: “Ref_2”]

Second_VC

```
    var SecondArray : BasketArray!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        table_view.delegate = self
        table_view.dataSource = self
    print(“retrieve:”,self.SecondArray)        
    }
```

Second_VC output;

> retrieve: [“cat”: “Tech”, “info”: “Android”, “orderid”: “Ref_2”]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because in your most nested for loop in First_VC, you have

```
self.SecondArray = BasketArray(info: info_, cat: cat_, orderid: orderid_)
```

Because it's in a for loop, self.SecondArray is set to the ID_1 values, then after that on the second run of the loop you're overwriting it to be the ID_2 values. You want to be appending both the datas to the SecondArray, not overwriting them like you have here.

Comment: Thanks for answer. How can I solve this?

Comment: Your BasketArray, if it wants to store more than one Basket needs to be an array - so  
var SecondArray : [BasketArray?]. 
Then you want to be appending to that SecondArray, so SecondArray.append(whatever data you parsed)

Comment: Unlikely that it should be an optional in the array

Comment: I updated the question .  I'm observing all data in the first vc (override func prepare->send array), but I only one array observing in the second vc